# Issue with DropDownListFor() setting Width more than 300px MVC 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4, dropdownlistfor

I am doing a small MVC 5 project and I am using BootStrap v4.1.3.
In my View Code, below, I am setting the width to 300px.  However, it needs to be 500px.  I cannot make it bigger than 300px.  What am I doing wrong? thx.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CaseTypeList)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCaseTypeID, Model.CaseTypeList, "--Select--", new { @style = "width:300px;" })
</div>
```

Comment: Check your css. You probably have a `max-width: 300px;` set (from the `site.css` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke That was it!!  This was the css that was preventing it.
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
Thanks!!